# PHP-FPM child processes respawning three times every midnight

Tags: php-fpm

I just noticed this is happening on all of my Ubuntu 20.04 servers running php7.4-fpm. The php-fpm error log shows all child processes respawning every night (morning) at exactly midnight, but oddly they then respawn again within about 4 seconds, and then again in less than a second, and then are stable. Rinse and repeat. I have no cron jobs that would do this and on the production servers, pm.max_requests is 50000, 500 on dev that isn't even getting hit yet. The only midnight cron job is /etc/cron.d/atop. So far I can't find anything else useful in any server logs I can find.

EDIT: changed stopped to respawning

Any ideas where else to investigate?

Comment: Log rotation? See `man logrotate`. Look for additional `cron` jobs in `/etc/cron.daily/`, and in `/etc/anacrontab` (read `man anacron`). Look at the system logs with `sudo journalctl --since=23:59 --before=00:05`

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. I don't have `anacron` installed and `cron.daily` stuff runs at 6:25 AM, so that can't be related to a 12 AM issue. Also, `journalctl` unfortunately doesn't give me any further insight regarding this problem.

Comment: The log messages do seem like they could be from /etc/cron.daily/logrotate, but that's done at 6:25 AM, which doesn't align with the 12 AM occurrences, so it's very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, figured it out! The logrotate daily cron job doesn't do anything if /run/systemd/system exists. Instead, this is due to the logrotate systemd timer, which is part of the daily systemd calendar as shown by `systemctl list-timers`, which does show that the logrotate runs daily at 00:00:01.

The additional respawns didn't happen last night, which is likely due to a fix I made to an unrelated issue where a failed PECL build caused /tmp/pear to be corrupted.